# "play the video" vs "play a video"

Tags: word-choice, articles

Can I switch "the" to "a" in this context?

> **Tom:** Can you play ***the*** video?
>   **Ann:** Video? What video? (the person doesn't remember)
>   **Tom:** We watched ***a*** video 10 minutes ago.

Is the last sentence okay?
As for a learner who doesn't have the articles in her mother tongue, I want to be sure.

Another question: [go to a concert vs go to the concert](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/140453/go-to-a-concert-vs-go-to-the-concert)

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo No, there are two options, I suppose, in the meaning of the question **What video?** : 1) What are you talking about? meaning the activity per se, I don't remember watching anything, 2) What a video are you talking about? The articles in the reply are respectively **a** and **the**.

Comment: @Mv Log. No, there is but one option: "Video? What video?" means "What video are you talking about?"  That is, Ann's questioning response indicates that Tom's question has come "out of the blue".

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo How about the dialogue in "edit"? Do you agree with my teacher?

Comment: @J. Doe. The problem article is **the** in Tom's first remark. In using that article, Tom is assuming that Ann will know that Tom is referring to something in particular. Ann's reply indicates that she has no idea what Tom is referring to. If Tom wants to tell Ann that he wants her to replay the video they watched earlier, Tom, if he's not being snarky, would reply "The video we watched 10 minutes ago".  TOM NEEDS TO RESPOND TO ANN'S QUESTION, and that final statement by Tom is simply not a response to her question.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Okay, I get it here. But the last question: do you agree with my teacher?

Comment: @J. Doe: Your teacher's remarks, at least as you have presented them, are not relevant to the conversational scenario in question. For you to ask that question tells  me that you don't "get it".

Comment: Tom uses the article **the** in his first statement. In the concert example, the first statement uses the article **a**.  Totally different conversational context. The concert example does not apply.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I get the example with Tom and Ann. And I edited the question because I wanted to know what the natives think about the example with a concert because I agree with my teacher in this case. Plus, it is still relevant but the topic of our discussion here has been changed.

Comment: Ask a new question, then, @J.Doe.  Comments are for discussing the current question, not a springboard for new questions.

Comment: Feel free to add a link to this question for context if you decide to ask a new question. If you ask multiple questions in one post, then it becomes difficult to score the answers, which means that future visitors to your question won't know which answer the community likes for which question in your post.

Comment: I'm sorry - I wasn't very clear in my comment. I meant put a link to this question in the new question so that the people answering that one will understand what made you think about it.

Answer (score 2):

Articles are not mysterious once you understand their conversational purpose.

When speakers use the definite article, **the**, they are indicating to the listener that they have *something particular in mind*, and that they expect to listener to know what that thing is.

So, when Tom says to Ann "Can you play *the* video?" he is assuming that Ann knows which video he is referring to.

When Ann replies "Video? What video?" she is letting Tom know that she does not know which video he is referring to, and she is asking Tom for clarification. "Video? What video?" means "I have no idea which video you are referring to. Which one do you mean?"

If Tom is going to give Ann the clarification she requested, he needs to tell Ann which video he has in mind.  The idiomatic way to do so is to say:

"*The* video we watched 10 minutes ago"

or

"*The* video we talked about over lunch, *the* one you said you had a copy of".

or some other response that identifies the video Tom has in mind.

A statement like "We watched a video 10 minutes ago." is simply not a response to Ann's request that Tom identify the video he has in mind.  It might be construed as a mildly sarcastic response, chiding Ann for having already forgotten the video they watched just 10 minutes earlier, but in Ann's defense, who would ask to see a video they've just seen without using the word **again**???

Tom: Please play the video again.

Answer (score 0):

'a video' can be any video. 'the video' is the video people specifically know which video it is in the context.

Comment: Yes but the person still doesn't know what video I am talking about and as far as I know articles are important for the listener more than for the speaker.

Answer (score 0):

> [Articles](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/articles/) are words that define a noun as specific or unspecific. There are three articles in English language, "a", "an" and "the". Consider the following examples:
>
> > *After the long day, the cup of tea tasted particularly good.*
> >
> > By using the article the, we’ve shown that it was one specific day that was long and one specific cup of tea that tasted good.
> >
> > *After a long day, a cup of tea tastes particularly good.*
> >
> > This statement tells a general fact that any cup of tea would taste good after any long day.

So when we don't want to point to some specific noun, we use *a* (or *an* if it begins with a vowel), else we use *the*.

Hence, if you want to convey through your statement to play any video use ***a***, else if you want the listener to play some specific video use ***the***.

Comment: Really? What about *I married a Japanese woman*. Are you saying that the woman here is not specific? Certainly the speaker of the sentence has only one woman in mind. What about: *There's a dog chewing the fence*? Is this not  talking about a specific dog, which can be identified?

Comment: I think you have misunderstood about what I was trying to convey. Let's take your example. "I married a Japanese woman" ---> In this sentence the speaker is not pointing to any one woman in particular. It's more like he is stating a fact that his woman is from Japan.
And if the sentence is modified like "I married the Japanese woman who works in that restaurant by the corner", we are pointing to a particular woman here.. hence "the" is used. Please do correct me if I am wrong! I am a beginner !

Comment: This post doesn't answer the question. Can the poster swap the definite article with the indefinite in the short dialogue he or she has written? Is the usage of the article correct in their last sentence?

Comment: I second Mari-Lou. This answer is not an answer. It's just a most generic mention of a most general rule that has nothing to do with the situation at hand. Worse still, if I apply it to the situation at hand, I actually get the wrong answer. Worse *still*, after you applied it to the situation at hand, you actually got *two* wrong answers. This is horrible.

Answer (score 0):

It may be very much pertinent that they had been watching a number of videos and Ann failed to decide which one.  In this context the last sentence with indefinite article is very much correct. But if meticulously considered,  the sentence is pinpointing the video shown  ten minutes earlier. This answer by Tom must be qualified by any other sentence or demonstrative phrase. Otherwise you cannot use the sentence as it is now. Just use:

- That's it.
- That one.
- I like that.

Somehow you have to define it.  It is not  always necessary to use definite article exclusively. Context can decide on its own and your rendering.